# Dark Background issue due to transparency of view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, uikit, uicolor

I wanted to set the background of my `View` in some light green colour and with an `alpha` of 0.1 but when running the code, I get a dark background like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 44.0/255.0, green: 194/255.0, blue: 108/255.0, alpha: 0.1)
```

[image]

I am using a `ContainerView` for containing both `loginVC` and `singupVC`, but when I set up the `transparent` colour of the container view, this strange thing happens.

Does someone knows how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because when you present or show a view controller the underlying view controller is removed form the hierarchy so there is nothing to be displayed underneath. You can try to change the "presentation" property on your view controller in the storyboard if you have one or set it in code if you don't. I'm not sure what value(s) that won't remove the underlaying view controller so you have to try. I know that setting `modalPresentationStyle = .Custom` on the presented view controller will result in the underlying view controller not being removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately, it is not working